# In Azure DevOps project Repos not showing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

Even though I have Project Admin, Contributor access. In Azure DevOps project, Repos not showing/visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Organization Settings->Users->Manage user->Check the user's access level. If their access level is stakeholder, they cannot access the repository.

**Change user access level from stakeholder to basic.**

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after changing the user access level from **stakeholder** to **basic**.

Note - If you are using the free tier, you will have only 5 Basic users. You have to set up billing from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops