# Unable to Access Azure Repos in my Organization even with Project Administrator permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos, azure-security

I observed that Azure repo's are inaccessible to all member of my Organization, including myself. I'm not the organization owner on Azure DevOps but Im an administrator. I have checked that I have access to Repo service under Settings. I have also checked that I have appropriate permissions to Read Repo's under Repository > Security settings. I noticed that the only way I or any other users in my organization can access the repository is by making access "Public" but this isn't a solution and it's a stop gap.

Would appreciate any help that can point me in the right direction.

I checked Project Settings > Repositories > Security and I expect to see permissions for the individual Repos; I checked and can see that there aren't any settings there unless I Make the Repo public

Answer (score 0):

**According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156844/in-azure-devops-project-repos-not-showing#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Organization%20Settings-%3EUsers-%3EManage%20user-%3ECheck%20the%20user%27s%20access,Change%20user%20access%20level%20from%20stakeholder%20to%20basic.) by Kotha Ramesh Babu Make sure to change the User's access level from Stakeholder to Basic.**

> I added one User by visiting my Azure DevOps Organization Settings > General > Users > Add Users > Select Access level as Stakeholder and invite the user like below:-
>
> [image]

When I logged with same user with Stakeholder permission, Azure Repos were not visible, Refer below:-

[image]

When I logged in with the user with Basic Access level permission, Azure Repos were visible refer below:-

[image]

Comment: Noted. How do I change my stakeholder access level permission to basic access level permission